# Iniciar vue-datepicker con fecha actual y cambiar estilo

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy ocupando vuejs-datepicker para tratar el campo fecha del formulario, hasta el momento no he podido hacer que el datepicker se inicie con la fecha del día actual y tampoco que no se puedan seleccionar los días antes de la fecha que se está iniciando

Estoy ocupando este componente https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker

```
 <template>
   <form>
        <datepicker :bootstrap-styling="true"
                    class="form-control"
                    :open-date="openDate"
                    :format="customFormatter"
                    v-model="event_at">
        </datepicker>
   </form>
 </template>
 <sctipt>
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
  import moment from "moment";
  export default {  
   components: { 
       Datepicker,
   },
   data () {
     return {
          event_at: '',
          openDate: new Date(),
   },
   method: {
      customFormatter(date) {
            return moment(date).format('D MMMM YYYY');
      },
   }
}
</script>
```

También el input en la vista queda de este color:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea? ocupo Vuejs 2

Comment: Resolvió su problema ? en principio debería resolverse simplemente con añadir el `new Date]()` a `v-model` es decir `event_at : new  Date()`

Answer (score 0):

La idea principal de porque nunca muestra la fecha actual es simplemente porque está asignando un `v-model` en blanco  `event_at` y esa directiva es la prioridad para un valor en un componente.

Para `setear` a la fecha actual puede simplemente decir que `event_at` de data sea igual a `new Date()` *(hasta el momento es la única solución para la libreria)*

**Componente**

```
<template>
   <form>
        <datepicker 
        :bootstrap-styling="true"
        class="form-control"
        :format="customFormatter"
        v-model="event_at"></datepicker>
   </form>
 </template>
 <sctipt>
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
  import moment from "moment";
  export default {  
   components: { 
       Datepicker,
   },
   data () {
     return {
          event_at: new Date(),
   },
   method: {
      customFormatter(date) {
            return moment(date).format('D MMMM YYYY');
      },
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción `open-date` sirve para abrir la vista del calendario en esa fecha, no para poner esa fecha por defecto, para tal acción trabaja directamente con el modelo `event_at` poniendo el valor por defecto `new Date()`.

Para restringir la selección de fechas usa el mismo valor `new Date()` en la instrucción `disabled-dates`.

Y para corregir el estilo visual usa la instrucción `input-class` en vez de sólo poner `class`:

```
<template>
    <form>
        <datepicker :bootstrap-styling="true"
                    input-class="form-control"
                    :open-date="openDate"
                    :format="customFormatter"
                    :disabled-dates="{ to: new Date() }"
                    v-model="event_at">
        </datepicker>
    </form>
</template>
<script>
    import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
    import moment from "moment";
    export default {  
        components: { 
            Datepicker,
        },
        data () {
            return {
                event_at: new Date(),
                openDate: new Date()
            }
        },
        method: {
            customFormatter(date) {
                return moment(date).format('D MMMM YYYY');
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Documentación](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

solo le voy ayuda en la fecha

importamos la libreria en el inicio de VUE
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment

```
import Vue from "vue";
import moment from "moment";
```

obtenemos  una función en VUE

```
obtener_fecha_hoy(){

console.info(new Date());
var hoy= new Date();//Fri Mar 12 2021 16:45:08 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)
            
var  data = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-D');
console.info(data);//2021-03-12

}
```